# jQuery show first two replies, hide the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

The comments are threaded three levels deep. The grandparent (depth-1) comments are all shown. I'd like to show the first two depth-2 replies (parent class comment) to every grandparent comment, and let the rest be hidden and displayed with toggle button (ideally one that changes text between "hide" and "show"). The depth-3 replies should all be hidden unless there is only one depth-2 reply, when, if possible, the first depth-3 reply should be shown so that a total of two replies is shown in all scenarios.

I have managed to toggle all depth-3 replies in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Frpmj/)

Here is the markup and javascript (updated):

```
<div id="comments">
  <ol class="commentlist">
    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even thread-even depth-1" id="li-comment-677">
      <div id="comment-677" class="grandparent">
        <div class="comment-inner">comment-677
        </div>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-2" id="li-comment-678">
                <div id="comment-678" class="parent">
                    <div class="comment-inner">comment-678</div>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-3" id="li-comment-680">
                            <div id="comment-680">
                                <div class="comment-inner">comment-680</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-686">
                            <div id="comment-686">
                                <div class="comment-inner">comment-686</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-3" id="li-comment-688">
                            <div id="comment-688">
                                <div class="comment-inner">comment-688</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-689">
                            <div id="comment-689">
                                <div class="comment-inner">comment-689</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>   

    <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt thread-odd thread-alt depth-1" id="li-comment-679">
      <div id="comment-679" class="grandparent">
        <div class="comment-inner">comment-679
        </div>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-2" id="li-comment-682">
              <div id="comment-682" class="parent">
                  <div class="comment-inner">comment-682</div>
                <ul class="children">
                   <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin odd alt depth-3" id="li-comment-690">
                      <div id="comment-690">
                          <div class="comment-inner">comment-690</div>
                      </div>
                   </li>
                </ul>
               </div>
            </li>

            <li class="comment byuser comment-author-admin even depth-2" id="li-comment-691">
                <div id="comment-691" class="parent">
                  <div class="comment-inner">comment-691</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>           

   <ol>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#toggle-all').click(function() {` what's that guy supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do basically the same thing you've done for the third level, but using a `gt()` (zero-based) selector to skip the first two replies:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Frpmj/3

```
$(this).next('ul').find('li:gt(1)').slideToggle();
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/